# Can every smooth sine function be given a smooth argument?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, trigonometry, derivatives

Here's a conjecture that I believe to be true, but I couldn't find a proof:

Let $\alpha: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\sin\alpha$ is smooth.
Then there is a *smooth* function $\tilde{\alpha}: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $\sin\tilde{\alpha}=\sin\alpha$.

Does anybody have a proof or a counterexample?

Comment: Since $\sin(\alpha(x))$ is a smooth function then it means that derivatives with respect to $x$ of all orders exist. This would imply that the derivatives of $\alpha(x)$ of all orders exist hence $\alpha(x)$ is a smooth function. Set $\alpha(x)+2\pi=\tilde{\alpha}(x)$.

Comment: @Adrian: Your "This would imply" is wrong.  For example, take $\alpha(x) = \cases{x & if $x \le 0$\cr x + 2 \pi & otherwise\cr}$.  Then $\sin(\alpha(x)) = \sin(x)$, but $\alpha$ is not even continuous, let alone smooth.

Comment: @Robert:You are correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret *smooth* as $C^\infty$.

Take a  $C^\infty$ function $f:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ such that $\sqrt{f}$ is not $C^\infty$, for example 
$$f(t) = \exp(-1/t^2)(\sin^2 (\pi/t)+\exp(-1/t^2))$$
(after [Georges Glaeser](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIF/AIF_1963__13_2/AIF_1963__13_2_203_0/AIF_1963__13_2_203_0.pdf), see also [here](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~bony/BBCP_jfa.pdf)). The function $g(t)=\sqrt{f(t)}$ is not even $C^2$ because 
$$g''(1/n)=n^4(\pi^2+4n^2e^{-n^2}-6e^{-n^2})\to\infty\quad \text{ as }n\to\infty$$
Let $\alpha(t) =g(t)+\pi/2$. Then $\sin\alpha(t)=\cos g(t) = h(f(t))$ is the composition of two $C^\infty$ functions, namely $f$ and $h(x)=\cos\sqrt{x}$.

On the other hand, $\alpha$ has unbounded second derivative near $0$, and there's nothing here that tweaking it to   $\tilde \alpha $ can fix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think, the statement might be true when you request both $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$ to be smooth (Yes, I meant $C^\infty$).

Comment: @Pete That is certainly true, and a known fact: a smooth map $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb S^1$ lifts to $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.